# How to Store Index of an Element from 2D Array into a 1D Array then Swap those Values

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing, swap, storing-data

I'm having trouble on finding how to store the row and column index of one element from a 2D array into a 1D array. Once those indexes are stored, I need to swap the elements with one another. Also, I totally understand that the use of 'using namespace std;' is not the best for practice, however that is what is required in this class. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//function prototypes
void minVal(int array2D[4][4], int array1D[], int numElements);
void maxVal(int array2D[4][4], int array1D[], int numElements);
void swapValues(int array2D[4][4], int array1D[], int numElements);


int main() {
    //begin program
    cout << "Array Swap Program" << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------" << endl;

    //initialize 2D array
    int twoDimensionalArray[4][4] = {
            {9, 8, 16, 7},
            {11, 6, 3, 14},
            {13, 4, 5, 12},
            {15, 1, 2, 10}
    };

    //display 2D array to user
    cout << "Below is the two dimensional array: " << endl;
    int row = 4;
    int column = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < column; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++){
            cout << twoDimensionalArray[i][j] << ' ';
        }//end inner for loop
        cout << endl;
    }//end outer for loop

    //initialize 1D array
    int oneDimensionalArray[4] = {{}, {}, {}, {}};


    //find minimum value using minVal function prototype
    minVal(twoDimensionalArray, oneDimensionalArray, 16);

    //find maximum value using maxVal function prototype
    maxVal(twoDimensionalArray, oneDimensionalArray, 16);
    return 0;
}

//function descriptions

//Minimum Value Void Function
void minVal(int array2D[4][4], int array1D[], int numElements){
    cout << "Searching array for minimum vale." << endl;
    cout << "Please wait..." << endl;

    //assign first element to the high variable
    int min = array2D[0][0];
    int row;
    int column;

    //begin search with second element
    for (int sub = 1; sub < numElements; sub += 1){
        if (array2D[0][sub] < min){
            min = array2D[0][sub];
            array1D[0] = array2D[0][sub];
        }//end if
    }//end for
    cout << "The minimum value of the 2D array is: " << min << endl;



    //assign row index to 1D array's first element
    cout << "It's located at row: " << array1D[0] << endl;


}//end of minVal

//Maximum Value Void Function
void maxVal(int array2D[4][4], int array1D[], int numElements){
    cout << "Searching array for maximum value." << endl;
    cout << "Please wait..." << endl;

    //assign first element to the high variable
    int max = array2D[0][0];

    //begin search with second element
    for (int sub = 1; sub < numElements; sub += 1){
        if (array2D[0][sub] > max){
            max = array2D[0][sub];
        }//end if
    }//end for
    cout << "The maximum value of the 2D array is: " << max << endl;
}//end of maxVal
```

I expect the output to be that the index values of oneDimensionalArray will be

{{minVal row index of 2D array}, {minVal column index of 2D array}, {maxVal row index of 2D array}, {maxVal column index of 2D array}};

Then the minimum and maximum values listed in the 2D array should be swapped.

I would appreciate the explanation of how to find these things too, not just the solution. Thank you!

Comment: *I would appreciate the explanation of how to find these things too* -- Use the debugger that comes with your compiler.  Second, that entire `minVal` function could be written with 3 or 4 lines of C++ code using `std::min_element` and no `for` loop.

Comment: *"I expect th output to be..."* An what output do you actually get?

Comment: And now that I look at the code, how do you expect such output when you haven't written any code to produce it? I *strongly* advise you to try writing code to find the maximum in a 1D array, before you attempt to o it in a 2Darray.

Comment: @Beta Hi. Actually, I have written the code for finding the minimum and maximum value of the 2D ARRAY. I'm not trying to find the value for the 1D array, as I stated pretty clearly in the above question. I am trying to grab the ROW and COLUMN index of the MINIMUM and MAXIMUM elements in the 2D array that I grabbed.

Also, the 'I expect the output to be...' is the outline stackoverflow suggests when asking a question, the output I get is the printing of the minimum and maximum elements of the 2D array, which is fine. However, I don't know how to grab and store the indexes of those elements.

Comment: *I am trying to grab the ROW and COLUMN index of the MINIMUM and MAXIMUM elements in the 2D array* -- That is a 2 or 3 line C++ call.  The question is whether an answer like that is what you expected.  Too many times an answer is posted, and the response is "I didn't learn that yet, so I can't accept the answer".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for the second part of your answer, however, I don't think you understood my comment or question. I am asking on how to store the row index and column index of an element in a 2D array. Why would I look at the debugger if I don't have the code in my program to produce the output? I build and run my code every time I write a block that can function. Asking for an explanation is me stating that, along with an example code, to explain how it works. Since I obviously do not have any idea.

Comment: You want to find the minimum value and the row, column of the minimum value.  You want to find the maximum value and the row, column of the maximum value.  Is that correct?  If so, again, that can be done with essentially two C++ function calls and a couple of lines of math.  The question that I have of you is whether this type of solution is what you're looking for, or some "long tedious" way of writing `for` loops, as you have done already.

Comment: You misunderstood my last comment. Let me try one last time, in simpler words: try something easier first.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't have any issues with accepting an answer, is a matter of having a starting place. I've been searching for some type of example like this so that I can at least try to understand it. Nothing of storing the index position of an element was discussed during lecture, nor can I find it in my class book, however it was instructed to produce a program that does it.

Comment: @theAlphaMelon -- When you say "index position", is it `(row, column)`, or is it the "distance" from the beginning of the array if the array was flattened to 16 elements?

Comment: An element in a 2D array has two indices (_ROW and COLUMN_). Hence, I consider the `int array1D[]` as a not so lucky choice. E.g. `std::pair<int, int> array1D` would IMHO fit to store pairs of indices, wouldn't it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I understand now. Either solution is fine. However, because we use 'using namespace std;' it's not been helpful for answers that contain the 'std::' formatting. 

I thought my code already has the code/solution to find the min and max elements within a 2D array. However, it has been instructed that we need to store the position of those elements (row position, column position) into the intialized 1D array. 

However, when I try to code it, it just outputs the minimum or maximum  element.

Comment: Well as @Scheff pointed out, you need a different type to store a (row, col), as that is two values.  If you just want the flattened distance, then you just need a single integer for each minimum and maximum.

Comment: However, next concern: `int array1D[]` makes me feeling bad. In edge case, you may have 16 min values in your matrix (e.g. everything 0). So, you should pass a `int array[32]` into function (to prevent potential out-of-bound accesses). As you specified the input array exactly (`int array2D[][4]` would've done as well), why you didn't for output `array1D`?

Comment: Following my previous comment: How do you know how many min or max values have been found? This is something you should return as well. In contrary to this, I don't understand the `numElements` parameter. `int array2D[4][4]` let me think this should be fix and known.

Comment: What I have been instructed:
The first function accepts 3 arguments: the two-dimensional array, the onedimensional array, and the size of the one-dimensional array. When calling this function
in the main function, it will:
1. pass both the two-dimensional and the one-dimensional arrays into function1;
2. traverse the two-dimensional array and find the element that holds the minimum
value;
3. store the row index of this element into the one-dimensional array as its first
element;
4. store the column index of this element into the one-dimensional array as its
second element.

Comment: After having read your code "trice", I believe to know the origin of your confusion: `int` is the type of values as well as of indices. IMHO, you just mixed that up. Have a look at this: `min = array2D[0][sub]; array1D[0] = array2D[0][sub];` You store the contents of element instead of its indices. If you found a min value in [0][sub] then you should store `array1D[0] = 0; /* row index */ array1D[1] = sub; /* col index */`, shoudln't you?

Comment: @theAlphaMelon Is your matrix guaranteed to be square (3 x 3, 4 x 4, etc.)?

Comment: @Scheff The reason I didn't return the the min/max values is because the compiler showed an error when I tried to code that into the void function descriptions. The reason for the no output for array1D (onedimensionalarray) is because I currently don't have anything within that array. I need to store the index positions of the 2D array into it, then print the output... I'm starting to feel like I'm not explaining this well. Everything I have written I derived straight from my class book after reading the chapters and studying examples. I don't think I could be that far off?

Comment: Btw. to check a 2D arrays, you should've two nested loops - one for rows, one for columns. To make this less complicated, initialize min with `array2D[0][0]` as you already did, and just ignore the fact that there is one useless check in the loops.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, it must contain those values in a 4x4 format in the populated 2D array.

Comment: _The reason for the no output for array1D (onedimensionalarray) is because I currently don't have anything within that array._ That's a misbelief: In your `main()`, you have `int oneDimensionalArray[4] = {{}, {}, {}, {}};` So, there are 4 values in your array. (I believe the `{}` make them 0 but I'm not sure.)

Comment: @theAlphaMelon -- ok, I posted an answer.  It basically attempts to show how to do both of these operations using modern C++.

Comment: And, in addition to Pauls solution: here a fixed version of your code: [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b809530e282d6212) (`minVal()` only, the rest as exercise for you) ;-) (And, please, don't forget to accept the answer as it answers your question.)

Comment: Concerning your last question _to swap the values_: Either use `std::swap` or make own code of the form `int temp = a; a = b; b = temp;`. Instead of `a` and `b`, you have, of course, to use `twoDimensionalArray[oneDimensionalArray[0]][oneDimensionalArray[1]]` and `twoDimensionalArray[oneDimensionalArray[2]][oneDimensionalArray[3]]`. (Btw. I consider the variable names as not so lucky choice as well...) ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a two-dimensional array stores its elements in contiguous memory, you can get both the minimum and maximum, plus the distance away from the start of the array using [std::minmax_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) and [std::distance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance).

Here is a small example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    //initialize 2D array
    int twoDimensionalArray[4][4] = {
            {9, 8, 16, 7},
            {11, 6, 3, 14},
            {13, 4, 5, 12},
            {15, 1, 2, 10}
    };

    // get both the minimum and maximum element in the 2D array
    auto pr = std::minmax_element(&twoDimensionalArray[0][0], &twoDimensionalArray[3][4]);

    // get the distances 
    auto dist_min = std::distance(&twoDimensionalArray[0][0], pr.first);
    auto dist_max = std::distance(&twoDimensionalArray[0][0], pr.second);
    std::cout << "Min Value: " << *(pr.first) <<  "  Distance: " << dist_min << "\n";
    std::cout << "Max Value: " << *(pr.second) << "  Distance: " << dist_max;
}
```

Output:

```
Min Value: 1  Distance: 13
Max Value: 16  Distance: 2
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eed974c89f4fe8a4)

Note the usage of `std::minmax_element` -- the parameters are basically the address of the first element in the 2D array, and the address of one past the last element in the 2D-array.  This gives us the range to search, and conforms to the requirements for `minmax_element` with respect to the iterators that are used for the first two parameters.

---

If the matrix is guaranteed to be square, then we can get the row and column of the minimum and maximum using a small bit of math using modulus and division:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    //initialize 2D array
    int twoDimensionalArray[4][4] = {
            {9, 8, 16, 7},
            {11, 6, 3, 14},
            {13, 4, 5, 12},
            {15, 1, 2, 10}
    };

    auto pr = std::minmax_element(&twoDimensionalArray[0][0], &twoDimensionalArray[3][4]);
    auto dist_min = std::distance(&twoDimensionalArray[0][0], pr.first);
    auto dist_max = std::distance(&twoDimensionalArray[0][0], pr.second);
    int row_min = dist_min / 4;
    int col_min = dist_min % 4;
    int row_max = dist_max / 4;
    int col_max = dist_max % 4;
    std::cout << "Min Value: " << *(pr.first) << "\n" << "Min Location: (" << row_min << "," << col_min << ")\n\n";
    std::cout << "Max Value: " << *(pr.second) << "\n" << "Max Location: (" << row_max << "," << col_max << ")\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Min Value: 1
Min Location: (3,1)

Max Value: 16
Max Location: (0,2)
```

So if you are to use this solution, you just need to adjust your code so that you hold the row and column index values in the one-dimensional arrays you've declared.

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de3d7c480c271afc)

Comment: I'll be, I would not have thought that a pointer to an element of a 2D array of `int` would satisfy the `class ForwardIt` requirement. I learned something. It surely can [C++ named requirements: LegacyForwardIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for all your help and direction and also allowing me to work through and test the remainder of my code!